# Find out what's wrong with pdf

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, acrobat

How can I find out what's wrong with my PDF file. I'm making a web application for digitally signing pdf documents. To do that, I'm doing a lot of stuff in the code like adding signature fields before inserting the actual signature. The code is too long to post here. The code is working fine for most of the pdf documents. However, for some pdf's it breaks the pdf, so it can't be opened with the Acrobat Reader.

Is there any way I can find out what's wrong with my pdf. The problem is that Acrobat Reader is giving me very general errors without further explanation.

The error I get is: *There was an error opening this document. There was a problem reading this document (14).*

Here is the signed pdf file that is making problems if someone wants to take a look:
https://easyupload.io/1a0i8x

Comment: If *the code is too long to post here*, distill it down to a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. If you can't provide the code when asking a debugging question, your question isn't suitable to ask here according to the [site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: My question wasn't about my code. I actually asked a question about pdf format itself. I wanted to know if there is any way I can see more details about what's wrong with my pdf file.

Comment: You're asking about a PDF that isn't working **after being modified by your code**, which means your code is breaking it. Without the code, we can't tell you why. In addition, if your question isn't about your code, then your question belongs on [su] instead, as it's not programming-relaetd.

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors in the cross references of the PDF.

Actually it looks like the source PDF had a cross reference stream (or at least hybrid cross references) and your program stored the cross reference data from the stream as a cross reference table, ignoring the fact that the entries referring to objects in object streams make no sense in a cross reference table.